# How to make package manager recognize libs that were compiled manually?

Tags: package-management, opencv

I had to compile `OpenCV 2.4` on my machine. How to make applications installed from synaptic do not ask to install `OpenCV 2.3` **libs dependencies** (since `2.4` is already installed in the system)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple (but it is more complicated to follow it):

you have to create a debian package of the code you compiled (OpenCV 2.4) and install that package. This way the package manager knows that the package exists.

Guides on how to create a package are:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete

http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/

http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/packaging/

There also seems to be a fake version of the above: create a package that pretends to be OpenCV 2.4 and install this package. How to do this is explained [here](http://eric.lubow.org/2010/system-administration/creating-dummy-packages-on-debian/)